# Callback function to move the object down not rendering right

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to do some extra engineering work on my project as part of my javascript lab.
I managed to get my dodger to move to the left and right but not to the bottom. Also when I invoke the event to make it go down (moveDodgerBottom), it doesn't do as asked and instead moves it up.
Can someone please help me with my code?

```
const dodger = document.getElementById("dodger")

dodger.style.backgroundColor = '#FF69B4'

function moveDodgerLeft() {
    const leftNumbers = dodger.style.left.replace("px", ""); //remember, the dodger styles left, right, etc are in relation to the parent object that it is placed within. 
    const left = parseInt(leftNumbers, 10);

    if (left > 0) {
        dodger.style.left = `${left - 1}px`;
    }
}

function moveDodgerRight() {
    const rightNumbers = dodger.style.left.replace("px", "");
    const right = parseInt(rightNumbers, 10);

    if (right < 360) {
        dodger.style.left = `${right + 1}px`;
    }
}

function moveDodgerBottom() {
    const bottomNumbers = dodger.style.bottom.replace("px", "");
    const bottom = parseInt(bottomNumbers, 10);

    if (bottom < 360) {
        dodger.style.bottom = `${bottom + 1}px`;
    }
}

//this function - moveDodgerBottom() makes the dodger go up instead of going down

function moveDodgerTop() {
    const topNumbers = dodger.style.top.replace("px", "");
    const top = parseInt(topNumbers, 10);
    if (top < 0) {
        dodger.style.bottom = `${bottom - 1}px`;
    }
}

//this function moveDodgerTop doesn't seem to be working


document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
        moveDodgerLeft();
    } else if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
        moveDodgerRight();
    } else if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
        moveDodgerTop();
    } else if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
        moveDodgerBottom();
    }
});
```

I tried using the technique before to get the dodger to move to the left by changing the ${left - 1} and then to the right by ${left +1}. I understand that with the bottom, the dodger needs an input of ${bottom +1} so I was thinking that the dodger would require a ${bottom - 1} to make it go up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the pattern of the four functions you created, maybe you can change :

```
function moveDodgerTop() {
    const topNumbers = dodger.style.top.replace("px", "");
    const top = parseInt(topNumbers, 10);
    if (top < 0) {
        dodger.style.bottom = `${bottom - 1}px`;
    }
}
```

with :

```
function moveDodgerTop() {
    const topNumbers = dodger.style.bottom.replace("px", "");
    const top = parseInt(topNumbers, 10);
    if (top > 0) {
        dodger.style.bottom = `${top - 1}px`;
    }
}
```

---

**Other method:**

Instead of using `style.left`, `style.right`, `style.top`, or `style.bottom`, maybe `style.transform` is the right option to make the div move. Fill in `style.transform` with `translate(x,y)` where the value `x` represents the coordinates of the X axis and the value `y` represents the coordinates of the Y axis. Both values can be filled in pixels (`px`).

```js
const dodger = document.getElementById("dodger")

dodger.style.backgroundColor = '#FF69B4';

let position = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}

function moveDodgerLeft() {
    position.x = position.x - 1;
}

function moveDodgerRight() {
    position.x = position.x + 1;
}

function moveDodgerBottom() {
    position.y = position.y + 1;
}

function moveDodgerTop() {
    position.y = position.y - 1;
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
        moveDodgerLeft();
    } else if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
        moveDodgerRight();
    } else if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
        moveDodgerTop();
    } else if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
        moveDodgerBottom();
    }
    dodger.style.transform = `translate(${position.x}px,${position.y}px`;
});
```

```css
#dodger {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dodger"></div>
```